# Failed to deploy OVF package. ThrowableProxy.cause A general system error occurred: Transfer failed: Invalid response code: 500

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, vmware-workstation, qnap, ovf

Versions:

ESXI: 7.0 Update 2 (build number 17867351)

VMware Workstation: 16.1.2 build-17966106

I exported a VM from QKVM (Qnap KVM) and been trying to import it into one of our ESXIs using vCenter, but to no avail. **It imports successfully to a locally installed VMware Workstation, though.**

The process I go through is (in vCenter, using Firefox): Right click on one of our ESXIs -> Deploy OVF Template -> I go through the wizard, I choose thin provisioning (it fails with Thick Provisioning all the same), I finish the wizard and the import tasks start just fine. But after a while they both fail.

Deploy OVF template task fails first around 60% with the following message: **[Operation timed out.](https://i.postimg.cc/jskmCxBy/Deploy-OVF-templae-timedout.png)**

Import OVF package task goes for a little while after Deploy OVF template task fails but then it fails as well with the following message:  **[Failed to deploy OVF package. ThrowableProxy.cause A general system error occurred: Transfer failed: Invalid response code: 500.](https://i.postimg.cc/hKD5rQB9/Import-OVF-package-throwableproxy.png)**

I also tried using ovftool to deploy the VM but it doesn't work either, below is cmd output:

```
C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool>ovftool -ds=datastore2-ea-i10-12 "D:\RPC\RPC.ovf" "vi://ab-a10-12.network.local/"
Opening OVF source: D:\RPC\RPC.ovf
The manifest validates
Enter login information for target vi://ab-a10-12.network.local/
Username: root
Password: ********************
Opening VI target: vi://root@ab-a10-12.network.local:443/
Deploying to VI: vi://root@ab-a10-12.network.local:443/
Transfer Failed
Error: Failed to transfer file [RPC-0.vmdk] to host [ab-a10-12.network.local] (response code:500)
Completed with errors
```

Comment: Hello, whats is OVF Size ? Sometimes fail because it's to big and send a time out.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, exporting a VM from one VCenter to another one.  What made the difference was to create a snapshot, before exporting the VM as an OVF.  After that, I was successfully able to deploy the OVF at the other VCenter.
Good Luck